# AVAudioSession App Volume Independent of System Volume

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avaudiosession

I'm writing an iOS app (using Xamarin) and it's a workout app. Pretty simple really. You start up iTunes, play some music in the background and this app has periodic voice prompts during different parts of the workout. It's a basic HIIT/Tabata timer.

I'm using `AVAudioSession` to duck the background audio when the voice prompts and it works as expected. But, I want the user to be able to set the volume level for the voice prompts via settings. I thought it would be as simple as setting the volume level on the `AVAudioSession` but soon found that it's read-only.

I don't want to change the system volume. **I only want to set the volume of my app's audio, independent of the system volume level.** This is possible. I know this because I have an app in front of me that does this very thing. My only problem is, I don't know how to set the volume for the audio in my app within my `AVAudioSession`.

So, does anyone know how to set the volume level for audio emitted by an app independently of the system volume level?

Below is the code I use to wrap my calls to activate and deactivate the `AVAudioSession`:

```
private void ActivateAudioSession()
{
    var session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
    session.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DuckOthers);
    session.SetActive(true);
}

private void DeactivateAudioSession()
{
    new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        var session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
        session.SetActive(false);
    })).Start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVAudioSession` as you said has a read only volume property but with:

`AudioPlayer` you can set the volume from `0.0` silent to `1.0` max  https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/AVFoundation.AVAudioPlayer.Volume/ like so:

```
        string path = NSBundle.PathForResourceAbsolute ("audiofile", "mp3", NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath);
        var url = NSUrl.FromFilename (path);
        var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl (url);
        audioPlayer.Volume = 0.5f;
        audioPlayer.Play ();
```

Or you could use `MPMusicPlayerController` but I think it can only play music https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/MonoTouch.MediaPlayer.MPMusicPlayerController.Volume/

Comment: Hah. I totally forgot that the audio player is what's controlling the actual in-app playback and has it's own volume. Thanks for pointing that out.